# Error when changing "Copy to output Directory" from "Copy always" to "Do not copy"

Tags: c#

I'm trying to save data in a database from my c# application. I added my db in the resources through the project properties, copy the string generated in my code, and change the "Copy to output Directory" from "Copy always" to "Do not copy". When I run the program it gives me this error:

Could not find file 'F:\Prova\Prova\bin\Debug\Resources\Student.accdb'

But the file is there.

Any help?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
    connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Resources\Student.accdb;Persist Security Info=True";

    connection.Open();

    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();

    command.Connection = connection;

    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Student(Student_ID, First_Name) VALUES ('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "')";

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    MessageBox.Show("Data saved");

    connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: Why did you change it to `"Do not copy"`?

Comment: Because I want to save what I type in the textboxes. If I leave it to "Copy always", the data inserted won't be saved. I can retrieve them, but when I close it, data are not saved.At least this is what's happening to me

Comment: usually when data is not saved in a database it's because one is not explicitly calling and or using the `COMMIT` command..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My psychic debugging powers tell me that you checked for `Student.accdb` in the source code files, but you didn't check for it in the binary files where your compiled project actually resides.

I would suggest copying the following path, exactly, into windows explorer and seeing if `Student.accdb` actually is there. taking not of the entire path.

```
F:\Prova\Prova\bin\Debug\Resources
```

---

If you don't want the file to be overwritten when you build, the best solution is to change `Do Not Copy` to `Copy if Newer`